# How to migrate EF Core to AWS RDS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, amazon-rds

I have a dockerized ASP.NET web api that I am running on AWS. I am planning on using RDS for the database, and I need to run migrations and I am unsure how I should go about this. My docker container only contains the dotnet runtime, so I can't just SSH into one of the machines and migrate. The RDS instance is set to only accept traffic from within the VPC, so I can't just run them from my machine. What would be the best way to run EF Core migrations into RDS?

I was thinking of maybe setting up a temporary EC2 machine, installing the dotnet SDK, EF Core and the source code, then running migrations and tearing it down. But I don't know if this is a good idea, or whether there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary EC2 instance for performing this sort of thing is fine, and a common practice.

I would suggest an alternative of building an AWS CodeBuild job to perform the migration task. However you might find your temporary EC2 instance useful for other things, like connecting to the database to perform ad hoc queries.